# How to parse a multiline response from ASIHTTPRequest and load data into a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, asihttprequest

I am trying to build a simple chat module in my iOS application. Right now, the application can send messages, which are handled by a PHP file and saved onto a database.

When trying to retrieve messages from the DB to display, the server returns a response of the most 10 recent messages in the following format

`msgid|userid|timestamp|message`

Note that these values are separated by a | character.

So a sample response from my server would be as follows

```
12|123|2013-03-02 09:15:16|Hey. How are you?
13|12|2013-03-02 09:17:31|Hey Matt. I'm good!
14|123|2013-03-02 09:18:02|That's great!
```

I need to load this response into TableViewCells, but I'm not sure how to go about parsing the response and saving the data locally.

I am newbie to iOS dev and I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be better if I post JSON data from the server and try to parse that?

Comment: Using JSON would be the ideal way to do this, but Darren's solution would work given you have a newline character. "\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a newline character after each message maybe you could use the NSString method:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

So:

```
NSArray *tableViewCellDataArray = [responseString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

If your response is in the format NSData, you can get an NSString by using:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

As for storing the data, you can store it in an NSArray property, or if you want persistent storage, investigate Core Data or NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I see that this would separate the lines of my response and save it into an array. How do I get about splitting each of the lines into components from this array ? 
If each cell of the table would represent a message, how do i assign these components to the cell? Thanks!

Comment: You will have an array of NSString objects, so you can use the same method to break it into its component strings (using the '|' character as the separator). As for adding it to your table view cell, it gets assigned in the UITableViewDataSource method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You will likely need to create a custom table view cell, I'm sure there are lots of posts on stackoverflow on this topic.